# Google Sheets: Number Formating

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to use this number format: 0.0,,"M"
Which will display the number 1,234,567 as 1.2M, however, once the number becomes 1,250,000, the value rounds up.
Is there a way to make it to where it shows the first 3 digits as shown before, but without the rounding?

Comment: Related https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74186/88163 , https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/79245/88163

Answer (score 1):

Try this format:

`0.0#,,"M"`

It will show 1,200,000 as `1.2M` and 1,250,000 as `1.25M`.

If you need more complex formatting rules, chances are that you will need to do it with a `text()` formula rather than cell number formatting.